# How to integrate the NAV with Outlook Express

Tags: navision, outlook, dynamics-nav

We are using Dynamcs NAV 4.0 we have to do the things in PO while send it sould go to the next desk for the approval and the person should know through the mail when it was post.please help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is automatically email somebody when a PO is created so they can review the PO and approve / rejct it as appropriate - is this correct?

Comment: After creating the po it will go for the approve on hierarchical ways and accordingly the person should approved from one desk to another the next person should know through the outlook mail